# Show the chosen option in HTML <select> after submiting the form or reloading the page

Tags: html, flask

My project is preliminary in flask/html/css with a little amount of javascript. So I have a  dropdown with some options. I save the value of the option by using `request.args.get()`.

```
<select name="company">
    <option value="Audi" >Audi</option>
    <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

After that I submit the form using

```
<input type="submit" value="Show data!"/>
```

The page will be reloaded and I can see the default value in the dropdown again. For example, if I choose   `Mercedes` I would like to see this value even after page reload. How can I do that, preferably only by using html/css?

**EDIT** 
What worked for me was:

```
<select name="company">
    {% if car in list_of_cars %}
        <option value="{{car}}" selected>{{car}}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value={{car}}>{{car}}</option>
    {% endif %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a programming language to achieve this. You are using Flask so do it in your template.

Store the names in an array. Generate the option elements by looping through the array. Compare each name to the submitted value in the form data, if you get a match also generate [a `selected` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes).